# Varrer string em múltiplo de 3

Tags: c

Galera como varrer uma string a cada 3 carácter?

Estava fazendo assim

```
for(x=0;str_P[x];x++){
 if (str_P[x] == 'ABC'||'abc'){ printf("1,");
 }if(str_P[x] == 'CBA'||'cba'){ printf("2,");
 }if(str_P[x] == 'BCA'||'bca'){ printf("3,");
 }if(str_P[x] == 'ACB'||'acb'){ printf("4,");
 }if(str_P[x] == 'CAB'||'cab'){ printf("5,");
 }if(str_P[x] == 'BAC'||'bac'){ printf("6,");
 }
```

Porém recebi esse erro

```
multi-character character constant [-Werror,-Wmultichar]
             if(str_P[x] == 'ABC'||'abc'){ printf("1,");
                            ^
multi-character character constant [-Werror,-Wmultichar]
             if(str_P[x] == 'ABC'||'abc'){ printf("1,");
                                   ^
error: use of logical '||' with constant operand
  [-Werror,-Wconstant-logical-operand]
             if(str_P[x] == 'ABC'||'abc'){ printf("1,");
                                 ^ ~~~~~
note: use '|' for a bitwise operation
             if(str_P[x] == 'ABC'||'abc'){ printf("1,");
                                 ^~~~~~~
                                 |
```

Comment: A formatação tanto da pergunta com resposta é feita com Markdown. Leia [Ajuda com Markdown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: O erro está em tentar fazer duas comparações simultâneas usando o operador `||` em `str_P[x] == 'ABC'||'abc'`. Você fazer algo assim:`(str_P[x] == 'ABC') || (str_P[x] == 'abc')` em todas as expressões.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g02T.png

Comment: `if ((str_P[x] == 'ABC') || (str_P[x] == 'abc')){}`

Comment: C pira que tmb tentei assim! (https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0azg.png)

Answer (score 2):

Tem várias coisas que não estão certas e precisa de rever e corrigir.

1. Strings em C são delimitadas com aspas duplas e não aspas simples. Aspas simples são reservadas para carateres apenas.
   Exemplo:

   ```
   char texto[15] = "texto"; //uma string para 14 letras
   char letra = 'a'; //uma caratere apenas
   ```
2. Comparação de strings em C é feita com a função [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) e não com `==` como fez
3. O combinar de várias condições com `&&` ou `||` tem de ter sempre dois operandos em cada comparação. Logo `(x == 3 || 4)` não está correto e tem de ser `(x == 3 || x == 4)`.
4. Quando faz `str_P[x]` está a aceder uma letra apenas, e por isso não tem sentido comparar com `ABC`. Uma letra nunca poderá ter o texto de 3 letras.
5. Para andar de 3 em 3 letras, basta alterar o incremento do `for`. Em vez de fazer `x++` pode fazer `x += 3`. Alternativamente pode testar se vai numa letra multipla de 3 com o operador resto: `x % 3 == 0`

Corrigindo tudo isso e tentado aplicar a lógica, mantendo o mais parecido possível podia fazer assim:

```
for (x = 0; ; x++){

    if (x > 0 && x % 3 == 0){
        char ultimas3[] = { str[x - 3], str[x - 2], str[x - 1], '\0' };

        if (strcmp(ultimas3, "ABC") ==  0 || strcmp(ultimas3, "abc") == 0){
            printf("\n1,");
        }
        else if (strcmp(ultimas3, "CBA") ==  0 || strcmp(ultimas3, "cba") == 0){
            printf("\n2,");
        }
        else if (strcmp(ultimas3, "BCA") ==  0 || strcmp(ultimas3, "bca") == 0){
            printf("\n3,");
        }
        else if (strcmp(ultimas3, "ACB") ==  0 || strcmp(ultimas3, "acb") == 0){
            printf("\n4,");
        }
        else if (strcmp(ultimas3, "CAB") ==  0 || strcmp(ultimas3, "cab") == 0){
            printf("\n5,");
        }
        else if (strcmp(ultimas3, "BAC") ==  0 || strcmp(ultimas3, "bac") == 0){
            printf("\n6,");
        }
    }

    if (str[x] == '\0'){
        break;
    }
}
```

Neste exemplo Construo uma nova string com as ultimas 3 letras e um terminador, para depois comparar com os textos pré definidos utilizando `strcmp`.  Repare que não avanço de 3 em 3 letras, pois pode passar o terminador `'\0'` caso a string de entrada não tenha um tamanho multiplo de 3, o que lhe gera comportamento indefinido e um potencial *segmentation fault*.

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/eFLaKp)

Comment: Shooow! Fiufiiu.